# Question about signature verification using Cloud KMS

Tags: javascript, digital-signature, sha256, node-crypto, google-cloud-kms

I'm trying to verify a signature generated with Google's cloud KMS, but I keep getting invalid responses.

Here's how I'm testing it:

```
const versionName = client.cryptoKeyVersionPath(
      projectId,
      locationId,
      keyRingId,
      keyId,
      versionId
    )

    const [publicKey] = await client.getPublicKey({
      name: versionName,
    })

    const valueToSign = 'hola, que tal'

    const digest = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(valueToSign).digest()

    const [signResponse] = await client.asymmetricSign({
      name: versionName,
      digest: {
        sha256: digest,
      },
    })

    const valid = crypto.createVerify('sha256').update(digest).verify(publicKey.pem, signResponse.signature)

    if (!valid) return console.log('INVALID SIGNATURE')

    console.log('SIGNATURE IS VALID!')

// output: INVALID SIGNATURE
```

This code will always log 'INVALID SIGNATURE' **unless** I use the original message instead of its hash:

```
const valid = crypto.createVerify('sha256').update(valueToSign).verify(publicKey.pem, signResponse.signature) // true
```

But using a local private key, I'm able to sign messages and verify them using their hashes:

```
const valueToSign = 'hola, the tal'
const msgHash = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(valueToSign).digest('base64');

const signer = crypto.createSign('sha256');
signer.update(msgHash);
const signature = signer.sign(pk, 'base64');

const verifier = crypto.createVerify('sha256');
verifier.update(msgHash);
const valid = verifier.verify(pubKey, signature, 'base64');
console.log(valid) // true
```

Why is it? Is there something different about kms signatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this example](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_sign) from the crypto module documentation and your observations, I'd say that you might've misunderstood how `client.asymmetricSign` works. Let's analyze what happens:

Your local private key code:

```js
const valueToSign = 'hola, the tal'

// Create sha256 hash
const msgHash = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(valueToSign).digest('base64');

// Let signer sign sha256(hash)
const signer = crypto.createSign('sha256');
signer.update(msgHash);
const signature = signer.sign(pk, 'base64');
// We now got sign(sha256(hash))

// Let verifier verify sha256(hash)
const verifier = crypto.createVerify('sha256');
verifier.update(msgHash);

const valid = verifier.verify(pubKey, signature, 'base64');
console.log(valid) // true
```

We are verifying `sign(sha256(hash))` using `verify(sha256(hash))`.

---

Your KMS code:

```js
const valueToSign = 'hola, que tal'

// Create sha256 hash
const digest = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(valueToSign).digest()

// Let KMS sign the hash
const [signResponse] = await client.asymmetricSign({
    name: versionName,
    digest: {
        sha256: digest, // we already say "we hashed our data using sha256"
    },
});
// We now got `sign(hash)`, NOT `sign(sha256(hash))` (where hash == digest)

// Let verifier verify sha256(hash)
const valid = crypto.createVerify('sha256').update(digest).verify(publicKey.pem, signResponse.signature)
```

We are verifying `sign(hash)` using `verify(sha256(hash))`.

---

Basically, locally you are signing **your hash** and verifying the signed hash. With KMS you are signing **your data** and verifying the signed hash, which is actually your signed **data**, hence your 2nd attempt with `.update(valueToSign)` works.

Solution? Hash your sha256 hash again before letting KMS sign it, since **KMS expects the sha256 hash of the to-be-signed data**, while the `crypto` expects the to-be-signed data *(which it'll hash itself given the algorithm you passed to `createSign`)*.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I was actually misunderstanding how crypto works, but now it's clear. 150 points to you!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very similar to the one from Kevin but from a different point of view, in other words.

When you use [`crypto.createSign(<algorithm>)`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createsign_algorithm_options) and [`crypto.createVerify(<algorithm>)`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createverify_algorithm_options) you are indicating the digest `algorithm` that will be used for signature creation and verification, respectively.

When you call `update` on the returned [`Sign`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_sign) and [`Verify`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_verify) objects you need to *provide your data as is*, `crypto` will take care of digesting that information as appropriate when you `sign` or `verify` it later.

In contrast, the [GCP KMS `asymmetricSign` operation](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.keyRings.cryptoKeys.cryptoKeyVersions/asymmetricSign) *requires a message [digest](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.keyRings.cryptoKeys.cryptoKeyVersions/asymmetricSign#Digest) produced with the designated `algorithm` over your original data* as argument. This is why you need to calculate the message digest with `crypto.createHash` first.

But please, as indicated, be aware that this fact doesn't change the behavior of the `crypto` verification process, it always requires the original data as input, this is why your code works when you pass your original data without hashing.

Although you provided a working example in your question for reference the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/create-validate-signatures?hl=en) provides additional ones.